# New way of dark mode in PyQt6/PySide6

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

There is 'old' way of setting dark mode in PyQt6/Pyside6 answered here: [How do I use QT6 Dark Theme with PySide6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060080/how-do-i-use-qt6-dark-theme-with-pyside6)

But I found official Qt blog post https://www.qt.io/blog/dark-mode-on-windows-11-with-qt-6.5 and I not sure how to applied 'new' way for PySide6.

Comment: you haven't asked any question

Answer (score 0):

With Qt 6.5, the GUI will follow the system style. If the OS is in dark mode, the PySide GUI will be too.

But, on Windows the default style is `windowsvista` and it doesn't have a dark mode. You have to use `fusion` style to get dark mode. (`windows` style also has a dark mode, but it's ugly as hell imo)

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('fusion')
```

Comment: Ok, got it, but how can I force PySide6 to use dark regardless OS settings.

Comment: With the 'new way' you can't. Maybe future Qt versions will make `QStyleHints.colorScheme` writable. See the 'Beyond Qt 6.5' paragraph of the article you linked.