# Python 3.11 made my pyQT application dark

Tags: python, windows, pyqt6, darkmode

I'm also learning python and making an application to calculate pile strengh. Last time I used python 3.10 and today I decided to update python to 3.11 and noticed that my application became dark according to the "Windows 10" theme. Dark theme looks cool, but it has some artefacts. I'm making this app for civil engineers who hate dark theme, and I want to turn it light permanently, at least, or make a toggle to switch dark/light theme.

[image: light]

[image: dark]

I assume, there must be one line which can allow/doesn't allow take system windows' theme.

Googling and GPTing didn't give me a good solution. The penultimate line makes mainWindow with artefacts as well.

[image: artefacts]

Thanks in advance.

```py
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    # Windows, Fusion, windowsvista
    app.setStyle('Windows')  # меняем стиль на "Windows"
    window = MainWindow() # Создаём объект класса MainWindow
    window.show()  # Показываем окно, красивое
    # window.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
    app.exec()  # и запускаем приложение
```

Comment: It seems strange that you're experiencing the change just with a different Python version, because those changes are normally done on the Qt side (which has absolutely no knowledge about Python). It's more likely that you also upgraded PyQt (most importantly, the underlying Qt version) in the meantime. In any case, since 6.5 Qt automatically uses the system palette, and if the system supports mode switching, Qt will follow it accordingly; there are no builtin solutions for this, but there are possible workarounds. For instance, you could hardcode a default palette based on a light mode »

Comment: » palette (just store it in a file using QDataStream) and use that if the user is starting the program for the first time while in dark mode; if the program is started in light mode, let it use the system palette and also store it in QSettings for future usage; if the program was started in dark mode and the system switches to light mode in the meantime (see the [related signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstylehints.html#colorScheme-prop)), reset the palette to the system one and store it as above. But, if your users really hate the dark mode, you could just tell them to disable it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've found a solution by myself (but IDK what's going on here. One day, I will):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74505698/23006884

This line:

```py
sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']
```

```py
darkmode=1  # light theme
darkmode=2  # dark theme
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use stylesheet before window.show()

```
def main():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) # Новый экземпляр QApplication
# Windows, Fusion, windowsvista
app.setStyle('Windows')  # меняем стиль на "Windows"
window = MainWindow() # Создаём объект класса MainWindow
window.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
window.show()  # Показываем окно, красивое
app.exec()  # и запускаем приложение
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is the same result as on last picture

Comment: Setting the stylesheet before or after showing is irrelevant, especially for what the OP is asking.